# Pageref inside alltt

Tags: pdftex

Here is minimal working example that shows bug:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage{alltt}

\begin{document}
\begin{alltt}
    \pageref{asd fgh jkl}
\end{alltt}
\end{document}
```

I would expect that output would be

```
??
```

Instead, what I get is

```
?? fgh jkl
```

\pageref works fine as long as there are no spaces in argument. When there are spaces, then all the words except the first one are outputed aswell. How can I prevent it? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is another good reason for not using spaces in labels. However, forcing them to be "real spaces" works:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage{alltt}

\begin{document}
\begin{alltt}
    \pageref{asd\string fgh\string jkl}
\end{alltt}
\label{asd fgh jkl}
\end{document}
```

Alternative method:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage{alltt}
\newcommand{\ttpageref}{\begingroup\catcode`\ =10 \ttpagerefaux}
\newcommand{\ttpagerefaux}[1]{\pageref{#1}\endgroup}

\begin{document}
\begin{alltt}
\ttpageref{asd fgh jkl}
\end{alltt}
\label{asd fgh jkl}
\end{document}
```

You can also use `\pageref` directly, with a more complicated setup:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage{alltt}
\let\latexpageref\pageref
\newcommand{\ttpageref}{\begingroup\catcode`\ =10 \ttpagerefaux}
\newcommand{\ttpagerefaux}[1]{\latexpageref{#1}\endgroup}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{alltt}{\let\pageref\ttpageref}

\begin{document}
\begin{alltt}
\pageref{asd fgh jkl}
\end{alltt}
\label{asd fgh jkl}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Marin The *real* answer is in the first line, though.

Answer (score 5):

You presumably don't just get the stated output but also the error

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
```

simplest way to avoid it is to hide the ref in a temp macro, Or if you prefer you can make the space safe with `\string`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage{alltt}

\begin{document}
\label{asd fgh jkl}
\def\foo{\pageref{asd fgh jkl}}
\begin{alltt}

    \foo

    \pageref{asd\string fgh\string jkl}

\end{alltt}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would it be possible somehow to pass argument through \foo for example so I would not have to define a new temp macro for each \pageref?

Comment: perhaps you prefer the second version with \string?

Comment: Yes, I like the second version more.